# Starting the android emaluator in ubuntu?

Tags: android-emulator

I created an avd of galaxy nexus with Intel atom x86. Now when I start the device, it gives me some cards to swipe. At last there is a card saying "To dim screen, cover it with your palm."  How do I do that? I am not being able to get the android menu and everything. And if I use arm the device wouldn't start and becomes black.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Are you sure the device is not Android wear?